# "Trois derniers bulletins de salaire du mois de juillet, d’août et de septembre" or without "de"

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, énumération

Would we say

> Trois derniers bulletins de salaire du mois **de** juillet, **d’** août et **de** septembre.

or

> Trois derniers bulletins de salaire du mois de juillet, août et septembre.

What is the rule here ? For example, perhaps I am wrong but I tend to think that

> J'ai besoin de toi, Louis et ton cousin.

and not

> J'ai besoin **de** toi, **de** Louis et **de** ton cousin.

but at the same time

> J'ai besoin **du** lait, **du** pain et **du** légume.

Comment: Now you make me confuse a bit as well. Apparently _besoin_ has more hits than _besoins_ in Google.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion!  I was trying to say that I was surprised to find even one hit for "J'ai besoin**s**" (not to mention 130K), because I was (and still am) pretty sure that it's always "J'ai besoin."  But because of finding all those hits for "besoin**s**" I'm not confident enough (as a non-native speaker) about it to edit another person's post.

Comment: @PapaPoule,Kenny: You should use [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact you can say both ([source](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1603)), but I find plural nicer .
Also, I think you should use plural (if anyone can confirm ?) :

> Trois derniers bulletins de salaire **des** mois de juillet, août et septembre
>   Trois derniers bulletins de salaire **du** mois de juillet, d'août et de septembre

**EDIT**
This is different with

> J'ai besoin **du** lait, **du** pain et **du** légume

Actually, it means

> J'ai besoin **de** le lait, **de** le pain et **de** le légume

but we use "du" to contract "de le", so if you remove from the enumeration "de", the rule would say

> J'ai besoin **de** le lait, le pain et le légume

which becomes

> J'ai besoin **du** lait, le pain et le légume

so we don't understand anymore which word is ommited ("de" here, which is not really in the first part of the sentence).

So you have to say :

> J'ai besoin du lait, du pain et du légume

or

> J'ai besoin de lait, pain et légumes

Note that légumes takes an "s" in the last sentence, because it is countable.

Comment: Note that you must uppercase the first letter of months… not in French. And *du mois* sounds acceptable to me in the second phrasing with ellipses.

Comment: Uh, don't know were do my rule comes from, I was sure you had to uppercase... About plural, it seems to be at writter's will, but it sounds nicer with plural

Comment: Is it required to have _des_ in your first phrase instead of _de_ ? Also, you mentioned that both ways are possible, yet I have the impression that we don't say _J'ai besoins du lait, pain et légume_ , no?

Comment: @Kenny I edited my answer to answer you.

Comment: I would expect “J'ai besoin du lait, du pain et *des* légumes”. *Le légume* is utterly weird. One would use the specific name for that vegetable instead.

Comment: On dira aussi, si l'on parle d'une situation générale : *J'ai besoin de lait, de pain et de légumes pour vivre* , sinon si je désigne les objets que ces trois mots représentent : *J'ai besoin du pain, du lait et des légumes qui sont sur la table pour préparer mon repas*

Answer (score 1):

I would say months are numerable quantities (you can count them, and parse a series of name as you would for numbers 4,5,6).
But if you want to insist on the individuality of each, them you treat them as objects with "de" or "du mois de".